# debugging php on mac?

Tags: php, debugging, macos, mamp

was wondering what was the best way to debug PHP on my local machine. I use MAMP on mac os 10.5

thanks,
Patrick

Answer (score 3):

Using [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) is a good start. Download the package and follow the instructions in the `INSTALL` file. It's fairly easy. Once this is done, add the following lines to your `php.ini` file:

```
;;[xdebug]
zend_extension="/Path/to/your/module/xdebug.so"
xdebug.file_link_format="txmt://open?url=file://%f&line=%1"
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 20
```

Don't forget to restart Apache after this.

Most debugging can be done using a simple `die(var_dump($some_variable))`. It's not very sophisticated, but with xdebug installed, the output of a vardump looks pretty good in a browser. In most of the cases this is enough.

If you need more control, you can add an `xdebug_break();` statement in your code and add the following lines to your `php.ini`:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

Again, don't forget to restart Apache.

Now, using a tool like [MacGDBp](http://www.bluestatic.org/software/macgdbp/) (or Eclipse+PDT if you must), you get a classic debugger. You can step though your program.

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

I've always thought the "best" way of PHP debugging on any platform is by using [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/), which can output debug messages straight into the Firebug window in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that running `php -l myfile.php` is great at catching syntax errors before I try and reload the page in my browser (and thus prevent the abominable [White Screen of Death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_screen_of_death#PHP_web_applications)).  Beyond that, I just point my browser to my local webserver and try to access the pages.

You can do some nifty things in your code itself (like using [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/debug_backtrace)), but that (obviously) requires you to put it in the code yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/)+[PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/) and [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/). To simplify things, get Eclipse for PHP Developers from the [Eclipse download page](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) rather than installing PDT as a plugin. Eclipse has a high learning curve, but it gives you all the debugger functionality you expect: instruction stepping, breakpoints, watches, even altering variables live.

If you don't like Eclipse or find it's too much for you, there are other [clients](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote#clients) compatible with XDebug.

Answer (score 0):

I also use eclipse+pdt and xdebug. If you're new to trying out debuggers you can try [zend studio](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/downloads-beta) which will setup things pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

Zend Studio is by far the best tool to use to create and debug PHP code. I run the community Edition of Zend Server on my dev Linux box and locally in a virtual machine on my MacBook Pro.

Take a look at the Zend website for details - it has cut my app development by two thirds!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a bunch of links like this one and others, here's a compiled solutions that successfully uses OSX's native Apache2 and XDebug together with MacGDBp and a Safari extension called [XDebug Helper](http://dokimay.com/index.php/mac-osx/56-configuring-xdebug-on-osx-mountain-lion).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it even without MAMP.

#### There is a way how to do it using:

- [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/)
- Homebrew
  ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
- Php + Xdebug

1) Install php and debug

```
brew install php70
brew install php70-xdebug
```

- In PhpStorm - check Preferences => Language and Frameworks => PHP
  Php language level: 7
  Interpreter: PHP 7.0.8 + XDebug  (or choose from [...])
- Check debug config:
  Preferences => Language and Frameworks => PHP => Debug => Xdebug section
  All checkboxes should be checked and set Debug port to: 9001

2) run server in your app's directory:

```
php -S localhost:8080
```

3) Add localhost:8080 to PhpStorm Preferences => Language and Frameworks => PHP => Servers:
Name: Localhost:8080
Host: localhost
Port: 8080
Debugger: Xdebug

4) Update php.ini:
Php => Interpreter => […] => Configuration file - Open in Editor
Add this section: (check zend_extention path through the cli)

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9001 (same as in Debug preferences)
```

5) Add Debug Configuration:
Run => Edit Configuration => add - Php Web Application

- Choose Localhost:8080 server

6) Click Start Listening for Php Debug Connections
7) Set up breakpoints
7) Click on Debug (Green bug)